# Spring Cloud Stream 3.1.2 RabbitMQ consumer not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Using spring cloud stream with RabbitMQ with config:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: rabbitmq
    password: rabbitmq
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          organization-created-in-0:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              republishToDlq: true
      bindings:
        organization-created-in-0:
          destination: vs.organizations.organization-created
          content-type: application/json
          group: requestGroup
          maxAttempts: 3
```

The application does not connect to RabbitMQ. Exchange and Queue are not created when the application is running. If they have already been created, there is no connection anyway. If `spring.cloud.function.declaration: organizationCreated` is added, the Exchange and Queue are created, but with the wrong name: [image]

Exchange `organizationCreated-in-0` instead `vs.organizations.organization-created` and Queue `organizationCreated-in-0.anonymous.z5pgPh4BT3SmlObBPQF4gw` instead `vs.organizations.organization-created.requestGroup`. How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Given the declaration is defined as `organizationCreated` (the method name), the binding name is `organizationCreated-in-0` not `organization-created-in-0`.

The method name is not hyphenated in the binding name, it is used unchanged.